# How to get data from shared preferences

Tags: android

I am saving phone no. in shared preference and in another activity I am trying to get phone no. from shared preference.

```
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "keyphone";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, "3454534565");
                                editor.apply();
```

In another activity I am using something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phone_id = sp.getString("keyphone","");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My problem is here I am not getting phone no. in toast message and I am getting empty toast.

How can I get phone no. in another activity?

Comment: please post what your `KEY_PHONE` variable is equal to

Comment: is the value of `KEY_PHONE`  equal to `keyphone` ?

Comment: what is the value of `KEY_PHONE`, check you are passing the same key at both place

Comment: I have used constant in place of "keyphone" in one activity.

Comment: @Digvijay wether or not this is the problem, what is the point of using a constant if you don't use it consistently everywhere?

Comment: make your constant public and use it from the other activity when you're requesting the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to store a value in Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("keyphone", "3454534565");
editor.apply();
```

And then this to retrieve it:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phone_id = sp.getString("keyphone","");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Main Problem is in here :  `editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, "3454534565");`

> To Write:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("KEY_PHONE", "3454534565");
editor.apply();
```

> To Read:

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("simplifiedcodingsharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phone_id= prfs.getString("KEY_PHONE", "");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: KEY_PHONE is a constant i have declared above its not a string.

Comment: the the prb is the constant and KEY_PHONE is not same that's why you can't retrive it.

Comment: it is a String constant, therefore the put-method will work.

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right except one thing.

When retrieving a String value you cannot just set the value field to "".

When retrieving a String, the default value is null, when retrieving boolean, default value is false and when retrieving a boolean, the default value is false.

So instead of using

```
String phone_id = sp.getString("keyphone","");
```

you need to use

```
String phone_id = sp.getString("keyphone", null);
```

Comment: what is the difference between these two?

Comment: "" is still a string, an empty string. null is not even a string.

Comment: a null string would be returned while no data found am i right? so why is it wrong?@AndroidAnton

Comment: the second parameter in getString is the default value if the shared preferences don't have anything under the key in question. You can set the default parameter to be whatever you want as long as it matches the getter's type.

Comment: Don't know where you're getting this from. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) : defValue - String: Value to return if this preference does not exist. This value _may_ be null.

Comment: default is null in my case. I just had to use sharedpref some days ago and default value is null. Why downvote?

Comment: Because what you're suggesting is wrong. The user __can__ define what the default value is. That's the whole purpose of the parameter being a string __variable__. Same with boolean; you can set the default value to either true or false depending on what suits your needs. Essentially you're defining a value that should be returned, in the event that the sharedPreferences don't hold an object with the key name you requested.

Comment: Ok, didnt know you can change the default value. I deleted that comment. Still, default value of String is null and I am 100% sure that's the asker's mistake. Please remove the downvote, cause my comment was wrong, not the answer itself

Comment: Downvotes are here to mark incorrect answers. You shouldn't take it personally and I definitely don't mean to be abusive, I apologise if I made you feel this way. If you edit your question to remove the suggestion that you __can't__ change the default value to what suits your needs, then I'm afraid my downvote still stands. Also, I'm not convinced that null is the problem either.

Comment: Updated. If you r not convinced, try to clone this